# Rounding Negative Numbers in G Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Simple question, is there a function that forces Sheets to round negative numbers mathematically? Presently it round based on absolute value, meaning that -1.5 rounds to -2.0, which is wrong. I want it to round to -1.0

Do I really have to make an if/else just to handle negative numbers properly?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use following formula:

```
=-ROUND(-A1-0.5,0)
```

And don't call it wrong, it's just different method of rounding.